# Match columns 1 if data not found then search column 2 oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause

I am trying to find a way if data is not found based on col1 of a table then search with other column value

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE COL1='123'

IF NULL
THEN 

SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE COL2='ABC';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This a typical SQL select statement involving an OR expression.

```
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE Col1 = '123' or Col2 = 'ABC';
```

Answer (score 1):

You want all rows that satisfy the first condition - but if no row matches, then you want all rows that satisfy the second condition.

I would adress this with a row limiting clause (available starting version 12c):

```
select *
from mytable 
where 'ABC' in (col1, col2)
order by rank() over(order by case col1 = 'ABC' then 1 else 2 end)
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

This is more efficient than `union all` because it does not require two scans on the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` with `union all` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where col1 = 123 union all
select t.*
from table t
where col2 = 'abc' and
      not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.col1 = 123);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting only one row, you can use:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE t
WHERE COL1 = '123' OR COL2 = 'ABC'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN COL1 = '123' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

With multiple possible rows in the result set, I would go for:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE t
WHERE COL1 = '123' OR
      (COL2 = 'ABC' AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE t2 WHERE t2.COL1 = '123');
```